# Matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am currently creating an animation of an oscillating graph in matplotlib (mpl) in a TKinter framework. I currently use the code:

```
self.f = plt.Figure()
self.canv = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=master)
self.canv.get_tk_widget().grid(master,column=2,row=2)
self.axes = self.f.add_subplot(222)
self.line, = self.axes.plot(x,y)
self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.f, animate, interval=0, blit=True)
```

Say for instance that the animation oscillates from +10 to -4, how could I set the axes range to +10 and -10? so that the absolute value for both the negative and positive parts of the axes are the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually:

```
self.axes.set_ylim((-10,10))
```

If you want to do it according to the data amplitude, you will need to extract min and max from y and set the range:

```
self.axes.set_ylim((-abs(lim),abs(lim)))
```

Comment: You're welcome. Click on the white tick on my post, it will mark your question as "Solved" with this answer and could be useful for other users.